# Check if my Internet provider supports and in my OS enabled IPv6/Teredo programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, network-programming, ipv6

I develop app (C++ Qt5.7) for the IPv6-connection via Internet. But have some problems with IPv6 channel accessibility verification. I would like to:

1. Checking for my Internet provider support of IPv6 and protocols Teredo, ISATAP & oth.;
2. Checking for enabling/disabling IPv6 and Teredo in my OS (Windows)
3. If IPv6 is disabled then set it up programmatically.

I tried to do something like this:

`RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\TCPIP6\\Parameters"), 0, NULL, 1, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hkey, &dwDisposition);`

But nothing no happens.. So I don't know - is IPv6 enabling possible on my machine or not.

Comment: I have try to write WinAPI code for the IPv6 support checking (by OS support, Windows 10 x64), but in that code there are so many errors.. and I erase all. About second pound of this issue: I'm absolutly don't know in what direction may be found solution. Can You help me?

Comment: @Steeve, have You once met with such task/problem?

Comment: Don't ask others to do your work for you (you're not paying them...) but do your best, show where you get stuck, and then ask for help here.

Comment: @SanderSteffann, I tried to do something like this:
`RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\TCPIP6\\Parameters"), 0, NULL, 1, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hkey, &dwDisposition);`

Comment: @Steeve, My question was re-completed.

Comment: @SanderSteffann, But this (2nd) my question is interesting/useful very low, more interest there is in the 1st - "Checking for my Internet provider support of IPv6 and protocols Teredo, ISATAP & oth..."

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586658/186260

Comment: You can also check [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr/). I think it allows you to query device capabilities. I'm not certain its a solution to your problem... Just a potential choice.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check for availability of network connectivity is to just try it. If you try to check first, the platform the application runs on might be configured in a way that you didn't anticipate and your check will fail when everything is actually working fine. The opposite is even more common: you check everything on the host and it looks ok, but then further in the network there is a problem and your code assumes it should work even when it doesn't. So don't check: just do and handle potential errors and recover from them.

Then about Teredo, ISATAP etc: don't

Teredo, ISATAP, 6to4 etc. are all protocols you shouldn't be using anymore. They are unreliable and unpredictable. If your user turned them off then there is probably a very good reason for that. Do **not** mess with your user's operating system settings!